# What is wrong with method findNumber which performs sequential search in an array to find an index

Tags: java, arrays, methods, output

I am supposed to get an output which shows player's numbers with their walks, outs, and hits, which comes from a .txt file. 
I did most of the programming but th output shows -1 for all the players.
Where is the problem ? 
Is it the findNumber method? 
Or other syntax errors?

```
 public class Baseball8
 {

// implementation of main program
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{

// 1) connect to input file
Scanner fin = new Scanner(new FileReader("baseball.txt"));

// objects used to store data
final int LIST_LENGTH = 20;

int number = 0,         // number, hits, walks, outs
    hits, 
        walks,
    outs,
    players,
        index,
        teamSize = 0;


// 2) output descriptive messages
System.out.println("This program tracks a baseball player's number "
           + "and their\nnumber of walks, runs and outs for "
           + "each game in a season.\n");


// 3) declare an array of LIST_LENGTH players
Player[] team = new Player[20];
// 3a) loop over the teamsize
for ( index=0; index<LIST_LENGTH; index++)

    // 3b) instantiate the i'th team member
    {
    team[index] = new Player();
    }

// 4)  loop on end of file
while (fin.hasNext())
    {
    // 5) attempt to input the data for the next Player
    number = fin.nextInt();
    hits = fin.nextInt();
    walks = fin.nextInt();
    outs = fin.nextInt();
    // 6) find the index of this Player's numbEr

number =    findNumber(team, index, teamSize);
    // 7) if player number is not in the list
if(number == -1 )
        {          // 7a) set the Number field for team[teamSize]
        team[teamSize].getNumber();
        team[teamSize].setNumber(number);
        // 7b) set the Hits field for team[teamSize]
        team[teamSize].getHits();
        team[teamSize].setHits(hits);
        // 7c) set the Walks field for team[teamSize]
        team[teamSize].getWalks();
        team[teamSize].setWalks(walks);
        // 7d) set the Outs filed for team[teamSize]
        team[teamSize].getOuts();
        team[teamSize].setOuts(outs);
        // 7e) increase teamSize by 1
        teamSize++;
        }   // 8) else player number is in the list
    else
        {
        // 8a) update the Hits field for team[index]
        team[index].setHits(hits + team[index].getHits());
        // 8b) update the Walks field for team[index]
        team[index].setWalks(walks + team[index].getWalks());
        // 8c) update the Outs field for team[index]
        team[index].setOuts(outs + team[index].getOuts());
        }
    }


// 9) display the results
displayArray(team, teamSize);
// 10) disconnect from input file
fin.close();

} // end of main


public static int findNumber(Player[] team, int index,int teamSize ) 
{    // 1) assume that this player_ number is not in the list
int Save = -1;
// 2) loop over the list length
for (int i=0; i< teamSize - 1; i++)
    {
    if (index == team[i].getNumber())
        Save = i;

    }
return Save;
// 3) exit the loop if the number is found
// 4) update the index on successful search  
// 5) return either the found index or -1
}

public static void displayArray(Player [] team, int team_size)
{
// 1) display headins of colums
System.out.println("\n\nPlayer\tHits\tWalks\tOuts\n" 
                  + "------\t----\t-----\t----\n");
// 2) loop over team size
for (int i=0; i < team_size; i++)
    {
    // 3) display i'th player
            System.out.println(team[i]);
    }
}
```

} // end of the class

This is the Player Constructor:

```
  Player() 
  { 
  Number= Hits= Walks= Outs = 0;
  }
   Player ( int Number, int Outs, int Walks, int Hits)
   { 
   Number= Hits= Walks= Outs = 0;
   }
```

Comment: Change `Save == index;` to `Save = i;`.  Also: (1) learn the difference between one equals sign and two, (2) start using lower case letters for variable names, (3) think more carefully about your variable names, in particular, don't use a name like `index` for a variable that isn't an index.

Comment: Also shouldn't i< teamSize - 1 just be i < teamSize if you starting value for i = 0?

Comment: `void` method doesn't return anything?

Comment: Very C style, sure you want to have Java?

Comment: Also, the `break` is always fired because it's outside the scope of the `if`.  Always use curly braces with an `if` or a `for`.

Comment: @DavidWallace I know the difference, I put the == by mistake, it wasn't like that. Thanks for advices. I would consider those

Comment: OK, if this is not your actual code, how can we know which of the errors here (I count 4) are really there in your code?  Much better if you just do a copy and paste, rather than retyping stuff.

Comment: Homework question detected

Comment: @DavidWallace Last time I copied all of my code and they just deleted my post

Comment: There is no point in asking us to find errors in program A, and posting program B.  If someone deleted you post on another occasion, it wouldn't have been because you copied and pasted your program.

Comment: It was probably closed , not deleted. If you'd like to post your code, see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: You don't really need `break;` just put `return i;` in the if statement.

Comment: @DavidWallace I posted the whole program. After compiling, It says unexpected return value. And I know My if statement is  not correct, but I don't know what its correct format should be if I wanna refer to the value from FindNumber method.

Comment: The reason for the "unexpected return value" is the error that veysiertekin pointed out.  You can't say that your method is `void`, then return something.  You need to change `void` to `int`.

Comment: @4castle it doesnt let me do that because My method is static void, and when I delete the void it gives a syntax error

Comment: @DavidWallace I thought I cannot say int before findNumber, Our teacher makes everything confusing. Thanks again

Comment: @4castle thanks. My other problem is with the if statement after step6. How can I refer to the value that I get from the method?

Comment: `int number = findNumber(...`

Comment: @DavidWallace sorry to bother again. but i updated the question. can you take a look at it for me? I appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Well,  is it working?  I see you have ignored most of the advice I gave you earlier.

Comment: @DavidWallace it is working and Our teachers wants us to use the variable he has chosen so I cannot change them. it compiles, The only problem is the players.. The output only shows -1 for players.

Comment: So,  you mean it's not working?

Comment: @DavidWallace  yeah simply its not working as it should

Comment: Then it's probably time for you to learn to use your debugger.

Comment: @DavidWallace what do you mean. I don't know how to use it. I mean Nobody taught us how to use it. Is there any links in here that you know of and  I can refer to

Comment: Your IDE will have some documentation about  how to  use the debugger. Or you can ask your teacher to show you.  That's what you've paid him/her for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By

> output shows -1 for all the players.

I suppose you mean the number of all players has been set to -1?
The findNumber-function gives the index of the player with the number you've given as an argument right?? So if you would make the following call:

```
findNumber(team, 10, 20);
```

it means you are searching for the player with number 10 in the `team`-array and you specify that the `team`-array represents a team with 20 players. The result of this function will then be the index(place) of the player in the `team`-array.

Well the reason your code is failing is this fragment of code:

```
    number = fin.nextInt();
    hits = fin.nextInt();
    walks = fin.nextInt();
    outs = fin.nextInt();
    // 6) find the index of this Player's numbEr

    number =    findNumber(team, index, teamSize);
    // 7) if player number is not in the list
    if(number == -1 )
    ...
```

You read the number of the player, his hits, walks and outs from the file (so far so good) but then you are searching for the player with the value of `index` as number and you are storing the index of that player (the result of the `findNumber`-function in your `number`-variable. So you replace the number you just read with the result of the `findNumber` function (that will always return -1 because you're looking for players with as number the value of the `index` that probably holds a number that doesn't exist in the team and never will because of this error). I don't think that's what you want...

What you probably want is to search the index of the player that has the number you just read from the file (stored in the `number` variable), store that index in the `index` variable and then check if that index, now in the **`index`** variable, is -1 (meaning, player with number `number` doesn't exist yet) or not. So the fragment above should be:

```
    number = fin.nextInt();
    hits = fin.nextInt();
    walks = fin.nextInt();
    outs = fin.nextInt();
    // 6) find the index of this Player's numbEr

    index = findNumber(team, number, teamSize);
    // 7) if player number is not in the list
    if(index == -1 )
    ...
```

I hope this helps!

In the code following this fragment you used your variables correctly.

Good luck!

Comment: WOW thank you. You are right. One of the comments said number= findNumber so I put number instead of index. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As an extra point our instructor wants us to overload the constructor Player. My question is that if I change the Constructor player, Does my program's result change?( or can I write the overloaded constructor in this program? )

Comment: You're welcome :) It was a bit confusing I agree but I think he just wanted to show you an example.

Comment: It depends on how you change it. If you want to add extra arguments the code you posted won't even compile anymore because you're using a constructor without arguments

Comment: but be carreful "override" doesn't mean "change"

Comment: Yes any comment is helpful . My program didn't compile, and by seeing these comments I could make it compile. Now I am trying to do some extra work to get some extra points but I don't want to ruin my previous program

Comment: "Override" as I know it (in Object Oriented Programming) refers to inheretence: creating a subclass that extends the `Player`-class

Comment: my server broke, But im gonna post the Player constructor in a bit and Write an Overloaded Constructor under it. How can I tag you if I posted that ?

Comment: I don't know, I read somewhere it isn't possible to tag someone in questions, only in comments but I can provide you with some useful links like [this one about inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) and [this one about overriding methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

Comment: Good luck with it!! ;)

Comment: I posted the constructor and My overloaded Constructor. Dos that look good? I didnt post the rest of my program.

Comment: Thanks for wishing me good luck. I wish you were my instructor :)) @j.baoby

Comment: My appologies I didn't see you had put 2 comments but the constructors you posted were ok! Creating 2 constructors will indeed let you choose which one you call according to the situation! Hope everything went well Have you actually seen if this was what your teacher was asking for??